# Validación de diferentes forms utilizando VeeValidate

Tags: vue.js, validación, veevalidate

Tengo la duda de como poder validar por separado formularios en la misma página, utilizando [Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) y su libreria [VeeValidate](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/), he estado haciendo pruebas pero no encuentro como acceder hasta el valor de cada `input` o poder englobar, por así decirlo, ciertos inputs para que solo valide esos, ya que toma en cuenta todos los inputs que estén con [VeeValidate](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/).

En el ejemplo que he realizado tengo dos formularios en la misma página y quiero validarlos por separado, ya que si por ejemplo doy click en aceptar dentro del form2, estando los campos del form1 vacios, da error aunque este bien escrito el email y viceversa, [También anexo un ejemplo en codepen por si les es mas cómodo](https://codepen.io/Villatoro/pen/LdKeKv?editors=1010).

```js
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#root_vee_validate",
    data:{
        exmp_basico: {},
        exmp_email: {},
    },

    methods: {

        validateOne:function(){
            app.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    swal( {title:"Exito!", text:"Campos llenos!", icon:"success", button:"Aceptar", closeOnClickOutside:false}); 
                }else {
                    
                    swal( {title:"Error!", text:"Campos vacios!", icon:"error", button:"Aceptar", closeOnClickOutside:false}); 
                }
            });
        },

        validateTwo:function(){
            app.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    swal( {title:"Exito!", text:"Email electronico correcto!", icon:"success", button:"Aceptar", closeOnClickOutside:false}); 
                }else {
                    swal( {title:"Error!", text:"Email no valido!", icon:"error", button:"Aceptar", closeOnClickOutside:false}); 
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css'>
  
    <div class="container-fluid" id="root_vee_validate">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col m10 offset-m1">
        <div class="col s12 m12">
          <div class="card-panel hoverable blue lighten-4">
            <div class="row">
              <h4 class="title">Ejemplo basico - form1</h4>
              <form>
                <div class="row">
                  <!---->
                  <div class="input-field col s6 l6">
                    <input type="text" name="nombres" v-validate="'required|alpha_spaces'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('exmp_basico.nombres') }" v-model="exmp_basico.nombres">
                    <label>Nombres</label>
                    <i v-show="errors.has('nombres')" class="fa fa-warning"></i>
                    <span v-show="errors.has('nombres')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('nombres') }}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-field col s6 l6">
                    <input type="text" name="apellidos" v-validate="'required|alpha_spaces'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('exmp_basico.apellidos') }" v-model="exmp_basico.apellidos">
                    <label>Apellidos</label>
                    <i v-show="errors.has('apellidos')" class="fa fa-warning"></i>
                    <span v-show="errors.has('apellidos')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('apellidos') }}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12 center-align">
                      <a class="btn btn-blue" v-on:click="validateOne">Aceptar</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!---->
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 m12">
          <div class="card-panel hoverable blue lighten-4">
            <div class="row">
              <h4 class="title">Ejemplo con email - form2</h4>
              <form>
                <div class="row">
                  <!---->
                  <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input type="text" name="email" v-validate="'required|email'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('exmp_email.email') }" v-model="exmp_email.email">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <i v-show="errors.has('email')" class="fa fa-warning"></i>
                    <span v-show="errors.has('email')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('email') }}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12 center-align">
                      <a class="btn btn-blue" v-on:click="validateTwo">Aceptar</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!---->
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.15/dist/vue.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vee-validate@latest/dist/vee-validate.js'></script>
```

Comment: No deberia estar esto componentizado? y cada componente validarse por separado?

Comment: Pues al utilizar el "app.$validator.validateAll().then((result)...." al parecer y valga la redundancia valida absolutamente todos los inputs que tengan el v-validate

Comment: Exacto.. en la documentacion dice que tenes que usar scopes, para saber que validacion estas aplicando...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun el componente, para validar varios modelos debes usar un scope

Para ello, basta con agregar a cada componente a validar  `data-vv-scope` y un nombre, y al llamar a la funcion de validacion, pedirle que valide solamente ese scope.

```
this.$validator.validateAll(scope).then((result)
```

En tu ejemplo, bastaria con hacer (solo incluyo una parte):

```
<div class="row">
    <!---->
    <div class="input-field col s6 l6">
        <input type="text" name="nombres" v-validate="'required|alpha_spaces'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('exmp_basico.nombres') }" v-model="exmp_basico.nombres" data-vv-scope="validar1">
            <label>Nombres</label>
            <i v-show="errors.has('nombres')" class="fa fa-warning"></i>
            <span v-show="errors.has('nombres')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('nombres') }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6 l6">
            <input type="text" name="apellidos" v-validate="'required|alpha_spaces'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('exmp_basico.apellidos') }" v-model="exmp_basico.apellidos" data-vv-scope="validar1">
            <label>Apellidos</label>
            <i v-show="errors.has('apellidos')" class="fa fa-warning"></i>
            <span v-show="errors.has('apellidos')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('apellidos') }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12 center-align">
                <a class="btn btn-blue" v-on:click="validateOne">Aceptar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!---->
</div>
```

Y al hacer la validacion:

```
validateOne:function(){
    app.$validator.validateAll("validar1").then((result) => {
        if (result) {
            swal( {title:"Exito!", text:"Campos llenos!", icon:"success", button:"Aceptar", closeOnClickOutside:false}); 
        }else {
            swal( {title:"Error!", text:"Campos vacios!", icon:"error", button:"Aceptar", closeOnClickOutside:false}); 
        }
    });
},
```

[Link a la documentacion](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/examples.html#scope-example)